Version compulsory while defining a transitive dependency in child modules when parent dep is present in parent module
I have a multi module java project X and has a child module Y. Also, there is a parent dependency which has a transitive dep.
The project X has parent dep in dependencymanagement and child module Y needs transitive dep. Then do I need to specify version of transitive dep in module Y. If yes then whats the point of declaring parent dependency in project X?
The transitive dep is declared in dependencies section of parent dependency pom.xml.
I am getting this error while doing this -
'dependencies.dependency.version' for com.abc.test:transitive-dependency:jar is missing. @ line 280, column 21


Versions from dependency management apply only for directly included dependencies, i.e. ones that appear in the "dependencies" block. If a child project needs a dependency (transitive or not), it must specify it in its dependencies block but without version. The version will be filled in by the dependency management definition for that same library.

@Alex That's the issue, why version of transitive-dependency is not being identified by the child module when parent module has the parent-dependency?

Child module needs to include "parent-dependency". It can't refer to "transitive-dependency" if it's not in the dependencyManagement. One reason for this is that "transitive-dependency" may be available, and with a different version, from many "parent-dependency"'s. That's why the child must be explicit in which "parent-dependency" it wants to provide the transitive one for it.
